# Programmatically start (autoplay) flowplayer after delay using jquery

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

I have a webpage that includes several video clips that each become visible after a button is clicked, and I'd like them to each autoplay.  Using the usual autoplay code for the html does not seem to work for all but the first clip, so I'm trying to play each one programatically using jquery after a short delay.  This code seems to work for the first in the series, but stops after that.  Thoughts?

```
$('.wpProQuiz_button').click(function () {
   setTimeout(function () {
      id = $('.fp-player:visible').attr('id');
      player = flowplayer(id);
      player.play();
   }, 500);
});
```